# Receiving AF_PACKET multicast on a Linux network interface

Tags: c, networking, multicast, ethernet

I'm implementing a non-standard / unpublished Ethernet protocol on Linux.  The Ethernet frames have EtherType `0x5eeb` and are multicast to `77:68:76:68:76:69`.

I'm struggling to write a simple program that can receive these frames while bound to a single interface.  I've attempted this in several languages now; here's the C version:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const unsigned short eth_type = 0x5eeb;

int main() {
    /* Open a socket */
    int fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(eth_type));
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Find out the interface index number */
    struct ifreq ifr;
    const char * if_name = "eth0";
    size_t if_name_len = strlen (if_name);
    memcpy(ifr.ifr_name, if_name, if_name_len);
    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);
    printf("Interface has index %d\n", ifr.ifr_ifindex);

    /* Add the interface to the multicast group */
    char mcast[] = {0x77, 0x68, 0x76, 0x68, 0x76, 0x69, 0, 0};
    struct packet_mreq mreq = {0};
    mreq.mr_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    mreq.mr_type = PACKET_MR_MULTICAST;
    memcpy(mreq.mr_address, mcast, 8);
    mreq.mr_alen = 6;
    if(setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, PACKET_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Bind to the interface */    
    struct sockaddr_ll addr = {0};
    addr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    addr.sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    addr.sll_protocol = htons(eth_type);  // Defaults to the socket protocol anyway
    addr.sll_pkttype = PACKET_MULTICAST;
    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Receive a frame and output some details */
    char buf [2048];
    struct sockaddr_ll src_addr;
    socklen_t src_addr_len = sizeof(src_addr);
    ssize_t count = recvfrom(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&src_addr, &src_addr_len);
    if (count == -1) {
        perror("recvfrom");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("Received frame.\n");
        printf("Dest MAC: ");
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++) {
            printf("%02hhx:", buf[ii]);
        }
        printf("%02hhx\n", buf[5]);
        printf("Src MAC: ");
        for (int ii = 6; ii < 11; ii++) {
            printf("%02hhx:", buf[ii]);
        }
        printf("%02hhx\n", buf[11]);
    }
}
```

If I remove the section titled `Bind to the interface` then I receive the frames alright, I just receive them from **every** interface on the system, not just the one I'm trying to listen to.  If I change either of the places where `eth_type` is used to `ETH_P_ALL` then I get all the frames arriving on the bound interface, not just the ones with my EtherType (and not just multicast frames, for that matter; `bind` doesn't seem to respect `PACKET_MULTICAST` in this case).

Is there some way to make `bind` and specific EtherTypes play nicely together?

I've tried this on Linux 5.11 and 4.9.  If anyone wants to do some testing, here's a short Python 3 program that spits out the frames.  You need the `pyroute2` package.

```
import socket
from pyroute2 import IPDB
import sys
import struct
import binascii
import time

ip = IPDB()

SMAC=bytes.fromhex(ip.interfaces[sys.argv[1]]['address'].replace(':', ''))
DMAC=bytes.fromhex('776876687669')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
s.bind((sys.argv[1], 0x5eeb))
#s.bind((sys.argv[1], 0))

dgram = struct.pack("!6s6sHH", DMAC, SMAC, 0x5eeb, 0x7668)
print(' '.join('{:02x}'.format(x) for x in dgram))

while True:
    s.send(dgram)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was actually the `PACKET_ADD_MULTICAST` socket option, which is a `SOL_PACKET` option, not a `SOL_SOCKET` option like I was attempting.  I'm not exactly sure what `SOL_SOCKET` + `PACKET_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` does, but whatever it is, it doesn't return an error and it breaks things.